# Are there any alternatives to Mechanize in Python?

Tags: python, mechanize

I'm using Python 3.6 while I have to fill in a form. Unfortunately, mechanize doesn't work on Python 3.
What do you suggest as an alternative to mechanize?

Answer (score 15):

[SeleniumRC](http://coreygoldberg.blogspot.com/2009/09/selenium-rc-with-python-in-30-seconds.html) with `selenium.py` is an alternative (and one of the few workable options if the pages you need to scrape have an important, "structural" role for Javascript operations, esp. AJAX-y ones, since Mechanize doesn't execute the Javascript on the pages it's scraping).

Answer (score 7):

For scraping and form handling you can use [lxml.html](http://blog.ianbicking.org/2008/12/10/lxml-an-underappreciated-web-scraping-library/) (it doesn't automate fetching and cookies though).

[scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) is a library specifically for scraping.

Answer (score 5):

I've been successful with [Splinter](https://github.com/cobrateam/splinter), a solution built on top of Selenium - while providing more pythonic API.

Answer (score 3):

I've used [twill](http://twill.idyll.org/) for a lot of my testing needs.  It works as a stand-alone language for "web browsing" or as a library from Python.  It actually uses Mechanize under the hood, so I'm not sure if it will meet your needs -- are you encountering problems intrinsic to Mechanize, or would you benefit from a high level layer?

Answer (score 1):

try zope.browser
http://pypi.python.org/pypi?:action=display&name=zope.testbrowser

Comment: It actually uses mechanize.

Answer (score 1):

scrapelib is another option : https://github.com/sunlightlabs/scrapelib