# Installing mechanize for python 3.4

Tags: python, mechanize

I'm trying to retrieve the mechanize module for python 3.4. Can anybody guide me in the right direction and perhaps walk me through the steps that I would need to take in order to make the correct installation? I'm currently using Windows 10.

Comment: `mechanize` does not seem to support Python 3: [1](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/faq.html), [2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mechanize/)

Answer (score 28):

unfortunately mechanize only works with Python 2.4, Python 2.5, Python 2.6, and Python 2.7.

The good news is there are other projects you can take a look at:
[RoboBrowser](https://github.com/jmcarp/robobrowser), [MechanicalSoup](https://github.com/hickford/MechanicalSoup)

There are more alternatives in this thread as well:
[Are there any alternatives to Mechanize in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662705/are-there-any-alternatives-to-mechanize-in-python).

Comment: Ok thanks. Hoes does RoboBrowser compare with Mechanize? Will I be able to perform the same tasks with it?

Comment: Also, where would you suggest I go to install the RoboBrowser module?

Comment: @Carnageta in order to install RoboBrowser you can go here: [RoboBrowser](http://robobrowser.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html).

In my Opinion RoboBrowser which wraps up BeautifulSoup and requests. Is your best alternative for Mechanize in python3

Comment: Thanks. The link says: "at the command line: $ easy_install robobrowser". What does this mean? Sorry, I'm not really familiar with these sort of things.

Comment: That's a command that should be run at command line in order to install the package but you could do it with pip as well which will be better if you are using a virtual environment.

Comment: I am able to use it in python3 as well ;)

Answer (score 2):

(edit) Mechanize 0.4.0 was release a few days ago (16th Jan 2019) and includes the python3 fixes from the mechanize3 fork so you could consider just updating to the latest mechanize release.

```
pip install -U mechanize
```

Comment: 1 star on github and no commits in 4 years = no thanks.