# Trying to find the right variable to screen scraping.

Tags: python, screen-scraping

I have code written out, have tested the first bit. (The logging into website) but I am trying to add on a screen scraping part into the code and am having a bit of trouble getting the result that I want. When I run the code I get "None" im unsure what is causing this. I think it is due to me maybe not having the right attribute that it is trying to scrape.

```
    import requests
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with requests.session() as c:
    url = 'https://signin.acellus.com/SignIn/index.html'
    USERNAME = 'My user name'
    PASSWORD = 'my password'
    c.get(url)
    login_data = dict(Name=USERNAME, Psswrd=PASSWORD, next='/')
    c.post(url, data=login_data, headers={"Referer": "https://www.acellus.com/"})
    page = c.get('https://admin252.acellus.com/StudentFunctions/progress.html?ClassID=326')


quote_page = 'https://admin252.acellus.com/StudentFunctions/progress.html?ClassID=326'
page = urllib2.urlopen(quote_page)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
price_box = soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'Object7069'})
price = price_box
print price
```

[This is a screenshot of the "inspect element" of the data I want to screen scrape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nfgvp.png)

Comment: I'm confused; you get page using requests (while logged in); but then get it again using urllib2 in which you don't log in... did you check whether the second one redirected you to a login page?

Comment: You create a request session, login, and then close it.

Comment: Sorry this probably sounds like a stupid question but how would I check if it redirected me to a login page?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think using requests and urllib2 to log in is a good idea. There is mechanize module for python2.x using which you could log in through forms and retrieve content. Here is how your code would look like.

```
import mechanize
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

# logging in...
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.set_handle_robots(False)
br.open("https://signin.acellus.com/SignIn/index.html")
br.select_form(nr=0)
br['AcellusID'] = 'your username'
br['Password'] = 'your password'
br.submit()

# parsing required information..
quote_page = 'https://admin252.acellus.com/StudentFunctions/progress.html?ClassID=326'
page = br.open(quote_page).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
price_box = soup.find('div', attrs={'class':'Object7069'})
price = price_box
print price
```

Reference link: http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/mechanize/browsing-in-python-with-mechanize/

P.S: mechanize is only available for python2.x. If you wish to use python3.x, there are other options ([Installing mechanize for python 3.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31774756/installing-mechanize-for-python-3-4)).